# Software minimal resolution is higher than my screen resolution

Tags: windows, resolution

We got a TPV which max resolution is 1024x768 and we need to run a software wich minimal resolution is 1280x1024, so some options are overlapping cause of this.

I have looked for some workarounds, like increasing or faking the desktop resolution, would it be possible to work with 1280x1024 resolution and scale it to 1024x768 so the monitor would work with it?

Another option would be to increase de software size and make it larger than desktop resolution, even when it would cause us to have to drag the window to work with it, but Windows caps the windows size to desktop resolution, even if I try to increase it programmatically using Windows API, its size won't exceed the desktop resolution.

We also contacted to the Software Developers, but they won't adapt the software for lower resolutions.

To connect another screen is not an option neither.

Any workaround would be appreciated.

**Specs:**
The terminal is **KT-700-LED** running **Windows 7**, graphics drivers are **Intel**

**UPDATE:** I forced windows to enable a second screen even when its not connected so it grants me more resolution despite the cursor can get lost in a non-physical screen, so with this, I increased the software's width  and made a script with move the software's window from left to right by pressing a key.

Comment: Use another software. No really, if a software doesn't work with your device don't use it. That would be the easiest solution to avoid that problem. As for changing the resolution, it depends on the display and the driver whenever you can change the resolution to a higher/lower one and how the scaling/interpolation works on the display. As an example on my current machine the Intel drivers support a setting for custom resolutions in the Intel control panel.

Comment: Answer deleted, and I apologize, after checking and finding the registry value I was referring to on the netbook, it appears to be a value associated with the Intel Atom's non-intel graphics chip.

Comment: @Seth I agree with you, but to change the software is not an option for us, instead, we plan to change our TPVs to others with higher resolution if there is not a workaround. About scaling/interpolation, yes, that's what I mean, but the current Intel drivers doesn't offer that option, I just updated it so i'll check again later

Comment: @Hydranix Well, wait, after updating drivers, the registry appeared, I just rebooted, what now? it would allow me to increase window size higher to desktop resolution or it was for anythingelse?

Comment: Remote desktop can be used for this as it supports smart sizing. You basically create a connection to another computer, and set the resolution manually by editing the .RDP file with a text editor. Ensure fullscreen is turned off. Then, either add smartsizing properties into the RDP file or after connecting change it. Programs such as Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7 also feature smart sizing.

Comment: The `xrandr` does this on Linux. By searching for `xrandr windows` I found several links: the most promising seemed to be [GiMeSpace](http://www.gimespace.com/). It's commercial software, but you can try before you buy, and if it does what you need it may be cheap at the price.

Comment: Restored answer and updated what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Regedit.exe`

Seach for this value: `Display1_DownScalingSupported`

Change it's value from `0` to `1`

Reboot

After which you can now set your resolution to unsupported sizes, which will not look good, but will work on most displays.




<sub>If your some reason you reboot to an unusable monitor, reboot into safe mode or the recovery environment and revert the registry edit</sub>

Comment: Not found :( can it be related to graphic card drivers?

Comment: Make sure you highlight in the SysTreeView (on the left of regedit) the top most key called computer before you search. If still not found I'll boot Windows 7 on my old netbook and look into how I did it.

Comment: yes it was and I confirm that it is not found, I have googled it and there is people that neither found it and had to update drivers, so that's what I'm trying now, however, if u can check ur netbook, I would appreciate it, thanks

Comment: Btw, I just searched it in another pc running Windows 10 with NVidia card and it didn't found it neither

Comment: hm, no luck, it doesn't allow me to set higher resolution, however I got my own workaround working, i'll update question later